# Create model with many columns using a constant pattern

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I built **flask** application connected with **mysql** database.

I try to push into my db table to keep list (vector with 500 floats).

Each column name should be `vector_var_{number_of_element}`

I would like to do it in smart way and not declare 500 fields from finger.

```
class FaceVector(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    vector_var_1 = db.Column(db.Float)
    vector_var_2 = db.Column(db.Float)
    vector_var_3 = db.Column(db.Float)
    vector_var_4 = db.Column(db.Float)
    (...)
    vector_var_500 = db.Column(db.Float)
```

I think about using `exec`

```
field_pattern = 'vector_var_{}'
for iteration in range(500):
    exec("%s = %s" % (field_pattern.format(iteration), db.Column(db.Float)))
```

Im not sure is it secure and is it a good practice?

Do you have better idea for this case?

Comment: If you want to do it in a smart way, why aren't you serializing all 500 values into a single field? I take it none of these need to be indexed, so why 500 individual columns?

Comment: This sounds like a bad design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used serializing as @Chase sugested.

https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/serialization/#numpy-array-flat-data

I changed my table definition into:

```
class FaceVector(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    vector = db.Column(db.Binary(4096))
```

During inserting and reading data I used this methods:

```
# Converting NumPy array to byte format
byte_output = np.array([ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ]).tobytes()

new_vector = models.FaceVector(vector=byte_output)


# Converting byte format back to NumPy array
array_format = np.frombuffer(byte_output_from_db)
```